# pgfplots: how to mark every nth (seventh) day on the x axis and in the grid?

Tags: pgfplots, calendar

First of all, this isn't science, this is tinkering about with pgfplots. My calculations probably are completely wrong.

I'm plotting a graph. The x axis are days. I'd like to highlight the sundays (March 15th, 21st, 29th 2020) in the graph. Maybe by printing the date as `\textbf{}`, even better were to get a highlighted line in the grid. Whatever.

I will continue this graph for the next weeks, so it would be even nicer to get the highlighting automagically each sunday.

The MWE:

```
\documentclass[paper=landscape, DIV=20, ngerman]{scrarticle}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
 \usepackage{libertine, babel}
 \usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}
% \usepackage{translator}%% Fehlermeldung
 \usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable, array, booktabs, mathastext, xcolor,
   colortbl, pgfcalendar}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{filecontents}{Verdoppelungszeit.csv}

Tag BRD RhPf
2020-03-10  654 18
2020-03-11  1089    25
2020-03-12  1892    52
2020-03-13  2576    102
2020-03-14  3421    121
2020-03-15  4195    168
2020-03-16  5433    325
2020-03-17  7156    442
2020-03-18  8198    474
2020-03-19  10999   637
2020-03-20  13957   801
2020-03-21  16662   938
2020-03-22  18610   1053
2020-03-23  22672   1177
2020-03-24  27436   1370
2020-03-25  31554   1591
2020-03-26  36508   1816
2020-03-27  42288   1971
2020-03-28  48582   2212
2020-03-29  52547   2396
2020-03-30  57298   2584
2020-03-31  61913   2726
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableset{% could be used in preamble
  create on use/brdoppel/.style=
{create col/expr={ln(2)/(ln((\thisrowno{1}-\prevrowno{1})/\prevrowno{1}+1))}}}

\pgfplotstableset{% could be used in preamble
create on use/rhpfdoppel/.style=
{create col/expr={ln(2)/(ln((\thisrowno{2}-\prevrowno{2})/\prevrowno{2}+1))}}}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{semilogyaxis}[
    unbounded coords=discard,
    height=16cm,
    xlabel=Datum, grid=major,
    legend entries= {Fallzahl BRD, Verdopplungszeit in Tagen BRD, Fallzahl Rh.-Pf.,
    Verdoppelungszeit Rh.-Pf.},
    legend style={%
      at={(0.9,0.535)}, anchor=east, draw=none,
    },
    date coordinates in=x,
    xticklabel={\scriptsize\day.\month.},
    x tick label style={rotate=45,anchor=north east},
    % x filter/.code{%
    %   \ifdate{weekend}{\color{black!50}}{\color{black}}%
    % }
]

\addplot [blue, thick]
          table [%
          x=Tag, y=BRD, xlabel style={font=\sffamily}]{Verdoppelungszeit.csv};

\addplot+ [blue, mark=*,mark options={fill=white}, thin,
          restrict y to domain=0.1:inf]
          table [x=Tag, y=brdoppel]{Verdoppelungszeit.csv};

\addplot [red, thick, mark=] table [x=Tag, y=RhPf]{Verdoppelungszeit.csv};

\addplot+ [red, mark=triangle*, thin, restrict y to domain=-1:inf, mark repeat=7]
         table [x=Tag, y=rhpfdoppel]{Verdoppelungszeit.csv};

  \end{semilogyaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\KOMAoptions{paper=portrait}\recalctypearea

\pgfplotstabletypeset[%
    use comma,% Komma als Dezimaltrenzeichen
    column type=r, 
    every head row/.style={before row=\toprule,after row=\midrule},
    assign column name/.style={
      /pgfplots/table/column name={\textbf{#1}}},
    columns={Tag,BRD,brdoppel, RhPf, rhpfdoppel},
    columns/brdoppel/.style={column name=BRD-Doppel, dec sep align},
    columns/rhpfdoppel/.style={column name=Rh.-Pf.-Doppel, dec sep align},
    columns/Tag/.style={date type={\weekdayshortname , \day.\month.},},
    every nth row={7[-2]}{before row=\rowcolor[gray]{0.9}},
]{Verdoppelungszeit.csv}

\end{document}
```

As you can read in the code, the `x filter` with `\ifdate{weekenend}`did not work, pdflatex went into a loop.

And by the way, if I uncomment the line `\usepackage{translator}` I get a error as well and have no idea why.

texlive 2020 on Linux.

[image: pic of graph]

Comment: You could use something like `xticklabel={\pgfcalendarifdate{\tick}{Sunday}{\color{red}}{}\scriptsize\day.\month.},` to format the xticks, probably you should then use also `xtick=data`, so that not every second sunday is missing.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you very much, that's an answer! The background for my question is that the data by rki on weekends usually show lesser new cases and numbers raise therefore much more on the beginning of a week, when the update includes the missing cases of Saturday and Sunday.

Comment: you don't need to explain the background to me - I just had to make saturday and sunday gray in a similar plot ;-).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Does the translator package work for you? Needed for the tabular on p 2. Please ignore this question, if you don't care.

Comment: Try `\robustify\translate` in the preamble.