# Get value of a row in pgfplotstable, which is x rows above current row

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable

I'd like to do a calculation to plot a graph. But I can't find a way to get the value of a certain row of a certain column in a loaded data file.

How do you get the value of a cell let's say 14 rows above the current row? For the previous row there is `\prevrowno{1}`, where the '1' means the column number.

I've written some lines of pseudo code in my MWE. But I've no idea how to get working code for `\GetRowVal`. I've seen this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/471230/4736), but failed to develop a working solution.

I really hope that my description here is clear. Please ask, I'd be happy to provide more explanation.

My MWE:

```
\documentclass[paper=landscape, DIV=30]{scrarticle}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{filecontents}{Verdoppelungszeit.csv}
Tag BRD
2020-03-10  654
2020-03-11  1089
2020-03-12  1892
2020-03-13  2576
2020-03-14  3421
2020-03-15  4195
2020-03-16  5433
2020-03-17  7156
2020-03-18  8198
2020-03-19  10999
2020-03-20  13957
2020-03-21  16662
2020-03-22  18610
2020-03-23  22672
2020-03-24  27436
2020-03-25  31554
2020-03-26  36508
2020-03-27  42288
2020-03-28  48582
2020-03-29  52547
2020-03-30  57298
2020-03-31  61913
2020-04-01  67366
2020-04-02  73522
2020-04-03  79696
2020-04-04  85778
2020-04-05  91714
\end{filecontents}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}


\begin{document}

%\pgfplotstableread{Verdoppelungszeit.csv}\loadedtable

%%% Does not work!
%\newcommand{\GetRowVal}[1]{%
%  Value of Column 1, #1 Rows abvoe Current Row
%}

\newcommand{\Subtraction}[1]{%
  \thisrowno{1} - \GetRowVal{#1}
}

\pgfplotstableset{% WORKS
  create on use/brdoppel/.style=
  {create col/expr={ln(2)/(ln((\thisrowno{1}-\prevrowno{1})/\prevrowno{1}+1))}}
}

%\pgfplotstableset{% HOW CAN I DO THIS?
%  create on use/brdoppelALT/.style=
%  {create col/expr={ln(2)/(ln((\thisrowno{1}-\prevrowno{1})/
%      \Subtraction{14}+1))}}
%}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{semilogyaxis}[
    width=20cm,
    unbounded coords=discard,
    xlabel=Datum, grid=major,
    date coordinates in=x,
    xtick = data,
    x tick label style={rotate=45,anchor=north east},
   ]

\addplot [blue, ultra thick]
          table [%
          x=Tag, y=BRD, xlabel style={font=\sffamily}]{Verdoppelungszeit.csv};

\addplot+ [blue, mark=*,mark options={fill=white}, thin,
          restrict y to domain=0.1:inf]
          table [x=Tag, y=brdoppel]{Verdoppelungszeit.csv};

%% Does not work!
%\addplot+ [yellow, mark=*,mark options={fill=white}, thin,
%          restrict y to domain=0.1:inf]
%          table [x=Tag, y=brdoppelALT]{Verdoppelungszeit.csv};

  \end{semilogyaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

A very nice extra would be a test, if a row (e.g.) 14 rows above the current row existed and if not, the calculation of the whole term had no result.

---

**Edit**

Question in comments: what are you trying to calculate. Short answer: see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/536120/4736)

I'm trying to calculate the time, in which a population of infected people doubles. The formula is

ln(2) / ln(q) , with q = 1 + p/100

The data is from the [rki](https://www.rki.de/DE/Content/InfAZ/N/Neuartiges_Coronavirus/Fallzahlen.html) page.

Now, after some weeks, the calculation is fiercely misleading, because the number of people, who regained health, is missing. People, who got infected at the beginning of march, are either healthy or... However, they won't infect anybody else and so it seems wrong to me to take them into account any longer.

So I'd like to "erease" the number of people out of all people who ever got infected, but who won't infect anybody else in the future, because they got infected too long ago.

An easy way (remember: this is not science, but tinkering with numbers) seems to be to take the number of newly infected people (this is `\thisrowno{1} - \prevrowno{1}`), and then subtract all the people who got infected until a certain time ago, let's say 14 days. We get a rough number how many people might be infectious *today*. This is the base to calculate the time needed to redouble.

To subtract the number of people being infected 14 days ago, I just have to look into the data, but I failed to put that into code!

Comment: It would be great if you could be more explicit in what you want to plot so that others do not have to guess. That is, please translate `{ln(2)/(ln((\thisrowno{1}-\prevrowno{1})/ \Subtraction{14}+1))}` into a formula in which one immediately knows what the terms refer to.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/231994/pgfplotstable-new-column-url

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat I amended my question, see the "EDIT". HTH! (Because I'm very courious if there is a pgfplots solution.)

Comment: I would like to ask you, again, to convert `ln(2)/(ln((\thisrowno{1}-\prevrowno{1})/\Subtraction{14}+1))` to a formula in which each term is explained. Now you write `ln(2) / ln(q) , with q = 1 + p/100` but do not tell us what `p` is. It would be so much easier if you explained each term.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat p is the interest rate.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat The whole thing is the opposite to the half time value.

Comment: I only want you to explain how a plot point is related to the data table. Something like `y(t)=ln(BRD(t)-BRD(t-14))` where BRD refers to the BRD column of your table. You just throw at us `\Subtraction{14}` bu there is no explanation of what this should achieve which I can understand.

Answer (score 4):

pgfplotstable can only access the values in the row before and after. You could naturally shift the column 14 times to access other values, but I would store the values in a expl3 seq and then you can access anyone and make whatever calculation you want to create new columns:

```
\documentclass[paper=landscape, DIV=30]{scrarticle}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{filecontents}{Verdoppelungszeit.csv}
Tag BRD
2020-03-10  654
2020-03-11  1089
2020-03-12  1892
2020-03-13  2576
2020-03-14  3421
2020-03-15  4195
2020-03-16  5433
2020-03-17  7156
2020-03-18  8198
2020-03-19  10999
2020-03-20  13957
2020-03-21  16662
2020-03-22  18610
2020-03-23  22672
2020-03-24  27436
2020-03-25  31554
2020-03-26  36508
2020-03-27  42288
2020-03-28  48582
2020-03-29  52547
2020-03-30  57298
2020-03-31  61913
2020-04-01  67366
2020-04-02  73522
2020-04-03  79696
2020-04-04  85778
2020-04-05  91714
\end{filecontents}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}

\pgfplotstableread{Verdoppelungszeit.csv}\datatable
\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N\l_keks_data_seq
\pgfplotstableforeachcolumnelement{BRD}\of\datatable\as\yvalue
 {
   \seq_put_right:NV \l_keks_data_seq {\yvalue}
 }

\pgfplotstablecreatecol[create~col/assign/.code={%
  \int_compare:nNnTF {\pgfplotstablerow-14}<1 
   { 
     \tl_set:Nx \entry{0}
   } 
   {
     \tl_set:Nx \entry{\seq_item:Nn \l_keks_data_seq {\pgfplotstablerow-14}}
   } 
   \pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/table/create~col/next~content}\entry
  }]{shift14}\datatable

\pgfplotstablecreatecol[create~col/assign/.code={%
   \tl_set:Nx \entry{\fp_eval:n{\seq_item:Nn \l_keks_data_seq {{\pgfplotstablerow+1}/2}}}
   \pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/table/create~col/next~content}\entry
  }]{half}\datatable


 \ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[string type]\datatable
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll try to understand, but however, with real data, the time in which the number of infected people will double, is much shorter (of course). If we take into account the group infected in the last week (those who don't know about their infection and are much more likely to spread it), the time for doubeling (Verdoppelungszeit) is about 6 days only!

Comment: Sorry I don't think I understand what you mean, but just to be sure: I didn't try to make sensible math in the example, I only tried to show you how you can do math, up to you to find the right formula (which imho doesn't really exist currently. Most of the data is not really comparable, as the criteria who gets tested  and the number of tests changed a lot).

Comment: You are probably right.

Comment: I beg to disagree with the statement "pgfplotstable can only access the values in the row before and after".  The macro `\pgfplotstablegetelem` allows one to access an arbitrary entry.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat I meant when creating a new column.

Comment: Also then you can use a function using `\pgfplotstablegetelem`.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat the docu says no "Limitations. Currently, you can only access three values of one column at a time: the current row,
the previous row and the next row. Access to arbitrary indices is not (yet) supported." (page 50). Can you show an example?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I added an explicit example at the end of my answer.

Answer (score 3):

It is very easy to plot some "delayed" data points. The trick is to define a pgf function `element` that returns elements of the table. This function can be used in constructions like

```
y expr={element(\coordindex,1)-element(\coordindex-14,1)}
```

The function is an almost trivial implementation of the `\getelem` macro from `pgfplotstable` with the subtlety concerning the interplay between `fpu`, which gets switched on by `fpu`, and integers.

The following plots the original data as well as a delayed version. It also computes the doubling time, i.e. the time it takes for the number of cases to double for the growth rate at a given date. They come in two versions, one using the full number of cases and the other only looking at the cases within the past 14 days.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{filecontents}{Verdoppelungszeit.csv}
Tag BRD
2020-03-10  654
2020-03-11  1089
2020-03-12  1892
2020-03-13  2576
2020-03-14  3421
2020-03-15  4195
2020-03-16  5433
2020-03-17  7156
2020-03-18  8198
2020-03-19  10999
2020-03-20  13957
2020-03-21  16662
2020-03-22  18610
2020-03-23  22672
2020-03-24  27436
2020-03-25  31554
2020-03-26  36508
2020-03-27  42288
2020-03-28  48582
2020-03-29  52547
2020-03-30  57298
2020-03-31  61913
2020-04-01  67366
2020-04-02  73522
2020-04-03  79696
2020-04-04  85778
2020-04-05  91714
\end{filecontents}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}


\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread{Verdoppelungszeit.csv}\mydata
\pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\mydata}%
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\numrows}{\pgfplotsretval}%


\pgfmathdeclarefunction{element}{2}{\begingroup
\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu,/pgf/fpu/output format=fixed}%
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myindex}{max(0,#1)}%
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\mycol}{#2}%
\pgfplotstablegetelem{\myindex}{[index]\mycol}\of\mydata%#1=row, #2=column
\edef\pgfmathresult{\pgfplotsretval}%
\pgfmathsmuggle\pgfmathresult
\endgroup}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{semilogyaxis}[
    width=20cm,
    unbounded coords=discard,
    xlabel=Datum, grid=major,
    date coordinates in=x,
    xtick = data,
    x tick label style={rotate=45,anchor=north east},
    legend style={at={(0.01,0.99)},anchor=north west,font=\sffamily,
    legend cell align=left}
   ]


\addplot [blue, ultra thick]
          table [%
          x=Tag, y=BRD, xlabel style={font=\sffamily}]{Verdoppelungszeit.csv};

\addlegendentry{F\"alle}          

\addplot [red, ultra thick]
          table [%
          x=Tag, y=BRD, xlabel style={font=\sffamily},
          y expr={element(\coordindex,1)-element(\coordindex-14,1)}]{Verdoppelungszeit.csv};

\addlegendentry{Neue F\"alle (weniger als 14 Tage alt)}       

\addplot [blue, mark=*,mark options={fill=white}, thin]
          table [x=Tag, 
          y expr={ln(2)/ln(1+(element(\coordindex,1)-element(\coordindex-1,1))%
            /element(\coordindex,1))}]{Verdoppelungszeit.csv};

\addlegendentry{Verdoppelungszeit}                  

\addplot [red, mark=*,mark options={fill=white}, thin]
          table [x=Tag, 
          y expr={ln(2)/ln(1+(element(\coordindex,1)-element(\coordindex-1,1))%
            /(element(\coordindex,1)-element(\coordindex-14,1)))}]{Verdoppelungszeit.csv};

\addlegendentry{Verdoppelungszeit von neuen F\"allen}                   
\end{semilogyaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}

%% ADDENDUM

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{melement}{2}{\begingroup
\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu,/pgf/fpu/output format=fixed}%
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myindex}{#1}%
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\mycol}{#2}%
\ifnum\myindex<0
\edef\pgfmathresult{0}%
\else
\pgfplotstablegetelem{\myindex}{[index]\mycol}\of\mydata%#1=row, #2=column
\edef\pgfmathresult{\pgfplotsretval}%
\fi
\pgfmathsmuggle\pgfmathresult
\endgroup}


\pgfplotstablenew[
% define how the 'new' column shall be filled:
create on use/data/.style={create col/expr={%
melement(\pgfplotstablerow,1)}},
create on use/shifted data/.style={create col/expr={%
melement(\pgfplotstablerow-14,1)}},
columns={data,shifted data}]
{\numrows}
\loadedtable

\pgfplotstabletypeset[columns={data,shifted data}]\loadedtable

\end{document}
```

[image]

Please note also that, as shown in the addendum, functions of the type of the above function `element` can be used for typesetting tables as well.

Comment: Not trivial, more in the direction of incredible. Thank you very much! I'm trying to understand, looking into the manual and into your code. Besides work, sigh...